# Is It A Generic Stack Data Structure Linked List Implementation in C?

Tags: c, linked-list, stack, generic-programming

My college professor taught us that a generic stack looks something like this (I basically copy-pasted this from the course support files):

```
typedef struct
{ size_t maxe, dime;  
  char *b, *sv, *vf;  
} TStiva, *ASt;

#define DIME(a) (((ASt)(a))->dime)
#define BS(a) (((ASt)(a))->b)
#define SV(a) (((ASt)(a))->sv)
#define VF(a) (((ASt)(a))->vf)
#define DIMDIF(s,d) (DIME(s) != DIME(d))
#define VIDA(a)  (VF(a) == BS(a))
#define PLINA(a) (VF(a) == SV(a))

// Function Declarations
void* InitS(size_t d,...);
int Push(void* a, void* ae);
int Pop (void* a, void* ae);
int Top (void* a, void* ae);

void *InitS(size_t d,...) 
{ ASt a = (ASt)malloc(sizeof (TStiva));
  va_list ap;
  if (!a) return NULL;
  va_start(ap,d);
  a->maxe = va_arg(ap,size_t);  
  va_end(ap);
  a->dime = d;
  a->b = (char*)calloc(a->maxe, d);         
  if (!a->b) { free(a); return NULL; }     
  a->vf = a->b;  
  a->sv = a->b + d * a->maxe; 
  return (void *)a;
}

int Push(void *a, void *ae)  
{ if( PLINA(a)) return 0;
  memcpy (VF(a), ae, DIME(a)); 
  VF(a) += DIME(a);           
  return 1;
}

int Pop(void *a, void *ae)    
{ if(VIDA(a)) return 0;
  VF(a) -= DIME(a);        
  memcpy (ae, VF(a), DIME(a)); 
  return 1;
}

int Top(void *a, void *ae) 
{ if(VIDA(a)) return 0;
  memcpy (ae, VF(a)-DIME(a), DIME(a));
  return 1;
}
```

Anyway, what this wants to be is a generic stack implementation **with vectors**, from which I don't understand why in the `Top`, `Push` and `Pop` functions need to refer to the stack data structure as a `void *`.

By generic, doesn't it want to mean that the **value the data structure wants to hold is generic**? This meaning that if you refer to your generic data structure as the typedef instead of `void *` it doesn't certainly mean that it's not generic.

I am asking this because I am about to create a Generic Stack implemented with Linked Lists and I am a bit confused.

This is my generic linked list data structure:

```
typedef struct Element {
    struct Element *next;
    void *value;
} TElement, *TList, **AList;
```

And for the Stack:

```
typedef struct Stack {
    size_t size;
    TList top;
} TStack, *AStack;

/* Function Definitions */
TStack InitStack(size_t);
void DeleteStack(AStack);
int Push(TStack, void*);
int Pop(TStack, void*);
int Top(TStack, void*);
```

Does anything seem not generic in my implementation?

Comment: You're going to want `Pop` and `Top` to take `void**`, so you can provide a caller with the pointer to the data. Since you don't know how large the data is, you can't `memcpy` to the provided pointer.

Comment: Must resist...  to complain... about macro abuse. Uh

Comment: I completely get you there. I feel the same way. I copy pasted that from the course support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generic means that it can hold ANY data type (`char*`, `int*`, etc..), or contain any data type. Void pointers `void *` in `C` allow you to cast items as such and get those items out(having to re-cast them on retrieval.

So, it allows the program to be ignorant of the data types that you have in your custom data structure.

Referring to the structure itself(as long as you are not specifying the data that is held in said structure), does not break generalities. So, you can specifically mention your `TStack` in your functions as long as the data that is manipulated inside of that stack is general(*id est* `void *`).

Answer (score 0):

`void*` is for generic purposes. Imagine it as a pointer to the memory, where of course the memory can hold anything. By `void*` you mean that you do not know what you point to, but you know that you point to something.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But why do I need to refer to my stack as a `void *` when then only thing I don't know is what kind of data I want to save in my stack, thus, I refer to that data as a void.

Comment: If not `void*`, then what? Oh, but wait, your functions (pop, etc.) will actually handle the data you store inside the stack.

Comment: Refer to the stack itself as `TStack` that stores generic `void *` values.

Answer (score 0):

Yes a `void*`can correctly implement a generic stack, but that creates a problem that you have no idea about the type of data you are storing in the Stack. The concept of `void*` is that it is pointing to some valid block of memory, but there is absolutely no clue as to the type of the memory. So, the code that is using this generic stack has to do type conversion explicitly. `void*` are used only to store data, manipulation with them are disallowed.